# How to war file execute Jetty-runner in command prompt

Tags: java, jetty, command-prompt

I am converting java class file as War File , So I want to execute war file  via command prompt . can any one suggest to me how i can run successfully through command prompt.

When I Have run through command prompt below Error showing in  my Eclipse Console .

```
D:\> java -jar c:\Jetty-runner.jar --port 8080 C:\firstsample.war
```

now deploying my war file, but it will error like-- no Transacation manager found if your webapp require one , please configure one , this type error i faced ......

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: You mean as an executable like what Jenkins provide? your question is not clear.

Comment: I ask when creation war file then it will be executed war file using jetty runner

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: maybe this site helps you: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner , if not maybe letting us know what error you are seeing would help...

Answer (score 0):

Just check your options

```
D:\> java -jar c:\Jetty-runner.jar -port 8080 -C:\ mysample.war
```

It should be like

```
 D:\>java -jar C:\Jetty-runner.jar --port 8080 C:\mysample.war
```

Better you keep `jetty-runner` and `mysample.war` in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jetty-runner always runs it in production mode, so you have to specify database as well as make sure that in database.yml file you have correct db configuration for production mode, e.g.

```
$java -Ddb=/Users/gouravtiwari/rubyapps/myapp/db/development.sqlite3 -jar jetty-runner.jar myapp.war
```

And your database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: <%= java.lang.System.getProperty('db') %>
```